# Recommended point estimate for non-normal distribution?

Tags: bayesian, inference, markov-chain-montecarlo, point-estimation

I have a rather non-normal marginalized posterior for some parameters, resulting from a Bayesian MCMC. Example:

[image]

I know that the actual distribution is what truly represents the parameter, but I need to report a point estimate. In such a case, I believe the mode would be better than the mean or median, but I'm not sure how to justify this other than saying "the mode *looks* like a more reasonable point estimate for the parameter".

Is there a more "statistical" justification for selecting either point estimate?

Comment: Why is the MAP not equal to the posterior mode?

Comment: Because this is the marginalized posterior for a single parameter, and the model has 6 parameters. I obtain the MAP as the mode of the posterior distribution, not for each particular marginalized posterior. I though this is how it should be done. Is it not?

Comment: A Bayes estimator can only be justified as minimising a loss function, which itself must reflect the reason for producing a point estimate rather than a full posterior distribution.

Comment: I'm sorry @Xi'an I can't follow your comment. Could you dumb it down a bit please?

Comment: I think @Xi'an is referring to the fact that any (standard) Bayesian inference through a probabilistic model is really only a specific type of loss-minimizing exercise (namely the negative log-likelihood as regularized with your prior belief). In fact, one does not even need a log-likelihood to perform Bayesian inference, any (integrable) loss function will do. While the posteriors resulting from general loss functions have been used for a while (usually named Pseudo- or Gibbs-posteriors), they do actually define coherent belief updates, see here: https://arxiv.org/abs/1306.6430

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to this paper, @Jeremias K. I was not thinking of this most interesting extension, but it is quite relevant. My simpler point is that a Bayes estimator does not exist _per se_, since the goal of a Bayesian analysis is to return a posterior distribution. If seeking a single-value summary of this distribution, some rule need be imposed, i.e., some comparison between uni-dimensional summaries must be available, which equates for me with the notion of a loss function (also found in game theory) that is minimised across the posterior distribution as, e.g., the quadratic loss.